# Need to SourceDisk Information on Azure Snapshot using PowerShell not AZ CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to the Source Disk information of azure snapshot using Get-AzSnapshot command but not getting the extact output

can anybody raised issue with Microsoft and has any alternate command to get the output

Comment: To get help on Stack Overflow people will epect you to put in some effort yourself as well, what have you tried and what problems did you run into?

Post the code you have tried and what problems you have with it and you are far more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Source Disk information of the azure snapshot is in the `CreationData` property. You can expand the details of the `CreationData` property like this:

```
Get-AzSnapshot -SnapshotName snapshotName | ConvertTo-Json
```

Then you can see the `CreationData` property like this:

[image]

It shows the resource Id of the Source Disk.

Comment: Thanks for the Command, Getting the Right Attribute which i am looking for